install reportlab==3.5.55 on Mac M2
I tried to install reportlab. it works with latest version but how can i install
3.5.55
pip install reportlab==3.5.55
is throwing error "Failed building wheel for reportlab"

py -m pip install reportlab --upgrade Released: Apr 18, 2024

Which Python version are you using?

python version 3.10.14
